# Im getting an syntax error on my .php page

Tags: phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

Im getting an syntax error on one of my .php pages. I have made an query in mysql and pasted in my .php page. when i do try to open the page its giving me an syntax error. **"Syntax error near 'From trolly inner join book on trolly.idbook = book.idbook where trolly.purchase' à la ligne 1"**

```
mysql_select_db($database_databaseConnection, $databaseConnection);
$query_BookPurchase = sprintf("Select book.name, book.price, From trolly inner join book on trolly.idbook = book.idbook where trolly.purchaseok = %s and trolly.id = %s", GetSQLValueString($varTrolly_BookPurchase, "int"),GetSQLValueString($varUser_BookPurchase, "int"));
$BookPurchase = mysql_query($query_BookPurchase, $databaseConnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_BookPurchase = mysql_fetch_assoc($BookPurchase);
$totalRows_BookPurchase = mysql_num_rows($BookPurchase);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma after `book.price`. Remove it.

```
Select
   book.name,
   book.price

From
   trolly 
inner join
   book 
      on trolly.idbook = book.idbook 
where
   trolly.purchaseok = %s 
   and trolly.id = %s
```

Comment: I have remove the comma after book.price and the syntax error went away.. but now im getting an new syntax error. "Champ 'trolly.id' inconnu dans where clause"

Comment: The `trolly` table has no column called `id`. Change it to an existing column

Comment: The column should be the one filled with `$varUser_BookPurchase`. So maybe it is called `userId` or 'customer' or something like that?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I did had a column call id.user but i forgot to add .user :)

Comment: and please note if the column is called `id.user` you should add escape characters around the column ( ` )

Comment: I dont have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma after the book .price and replace the Query by

```
Select book.name, book.price From trolly inner join book on trolly.idbook = book.idbook where trolly.purchaseok = %s and trolly.id = %s", GetSQLValueString($varTrolly_BookPurchase, "int"),GetSQLValueString($varUser_BookPurchase, "int"))
```